# Conversion to non-scalar type requested

Tags: c++, templates, generic-programming

In a homework assignment on generic programming, a program is not compiling. I'm supposed to fix this by inserting code only to the specified location and changing nothing else. I've attempted to do so by overloading operators to make the compiler understand what they mean for that custom type, but I still get the same errors. I'm now at a loss.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
struct TripleData {
    T m_first;
    T m_second;
    T m_third;  
    T getMean() {
        return (m_first + m_second + m_third)/3;
    }

    // INSERT CODE HERE
    void operator = (const T & value) {
        m_first = m_second = m_third = value;  
    }

    void operator += (const TripleData & tridata) {
        m_first += tridata.m_first;
        m_second += tridata.m_second;
        m_third += tridata.m_third;
    }

    T & operator / (const T & divisor) {
        return m_first/divisor;
    }
    //END OF INSERTED CODE
};

template <typename T, int N>
class GenericStaticMatrix {
    T m_data[N];
public:
    T & operator()(int i) {
        return m_data[i];
    }
    int getSize() const {
        return N;
    }
    T getMean() const {
        T sum = 0;                            //Error: conversion from 'int' to non-scalar type 'TripleData<double>' requested
        for (int i=0;i<N;i++) sum+=m_data[i]; 
        T ret = sum/(double)N;                //Error: conversion from 'double' to non-scalar type 'TripleData<double>' requested
        return ret;
    }
};


int main() {

    const int size = 10;
    int i;     
    GenericStaticMatrix<TripleData<double>,size> gsm_tdd;

    for (i=0;i<size;i++) {
        gsm_tdd(i).m_first = 1.1 + i;
        gsm_tdd(i).m_second = 2.2 + i;
        gsm_tdd(i).m_third = 3.3 + i;
    }

    cout << gsm_tdd.getMean().m_first <<endl;
    cout << gsm_tdd.getMean().m_second <<endl;
    cout << gsm_tdd.getMean().m_third <<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The code is invalid at least due to this operator definition because it returns reference to temporary onject      T & operator / (const T & divisor) {
        return m_first/divisor;
    }

Comment: `operator+=()` and `operator=()` should return a reference tho `*this` to allow for operator chaining. Also, a correct implementation of `operator=()` should check for equality to `this`.

Comment: are you aware, that once the solution is online, in principle it is worth zero credit points?

Comment: Yeah, I guess I shouldn't use `void`. And yes, I'm aware of it but I'm just reviewing this as an exercise. It's not worth any points anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code that needs to run generically for `TripleData<double>` is:

```
T sum = 0;                // (A)
sum += m_data[i];         // (B)
T ret = sum / (double)N;  // (C)
```

Just work backwards from the implicit interface that this code implies.

```
// (A) implies non-explicit construction from an int
TripleData(int ); 

// (B) implies operator+=, you have this one almost right
TripleData& operator+=(const TripleData& rhs);

// (C) implies division by a **scalar** - this should NOT modify the object
TripleData operator/(double ) const;
```

You're missing `(A)` completely - you wrote an assignment operator, but `T x = y;` isn't assignment, it's [copy-initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization). `(B)` is basically fine, and `(C)` you're taking the wrong type of operand. We're dividing by a `double`, not by a `TripleData<double>`.

Comment: That's it. I got the implied part all wrong. I should also return a reference value to `*this` instead of using `void` I guess. Thanks!